# Javascript Select Query on parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

i would like to run simple select query from [tutorial](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide/#queries-basic) page which looks like this :

```
        Parse.Cloud.define("tst", function(request, response) {
        var log = "LOG ";
        var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
        var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
        query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan");
        query.find({
          success: function(results) {
            alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
            // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
              var object = results[i];
              alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
              log +=object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName');
            }
          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            log += "Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message;
          }
        });
    response.success("Hello world!" + log);
    }
```

iam triggering this function via Android, using code below:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("tst", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<String>() {
            @Override 
            public void done(String result1, ParseException error) {
                Log.e("MPE"+OutfeedApp.TAG,result1.toString());  
            } 
        });
```

Problem is that after I call this funcion I can not see any output in log. Data are there so I should see some output. When I build same query on android client and avoid javascrip I see results. 
Iam trying to solve this issue for 5 hours but without any progress.
Please help :)
Thank you

Comment: You need to move response.success(results) inside success callback to return the result.

Comment: well i did that but "log" variable still doesnt contains any data from possible resultset

Comment: due to "Comment can be eddited for only 5 minutes" ----->
well i did that but "log" variable still doesnt contains any data from possible resultset and response.success(....) is not even called from  query.find, i dont understand this, iam new to JS but this is quite simple code which should work

Comment: you mean when u put response.success inside sucess callback log is empty or outside sucess callback. in js it is important to put it inside success callback. put it outside log will be empty and you will get no results.

Comment: when i put response.success("SUCC Hello world!" + log); into sucess callback its not called, also callback in error response is not called, only callback in the end of function is called, i dont understand that

Comment: that's because if you have response.success() immediately after query.find(), parse will ignore any other code execution. query.find() callback never have a chance to finish the task you ask to do. remove the `response.success("Hello world!" + log);`

Comment: Muhahahaaa, thanks wayne, now it works..